# Possible Bug with DateObject

Tags: date-and-time

So my questions is going to be hard to duplicate because I am not sure when or why it happens.  I've read here several bugs with [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html), but none of them include what is happening to me.

On **Mathematica 10.0.0.0** I start up a kernel and run the line:

```
DateObject[]
```

and I will get the current date:

[image]

I will come back after running several hundreds lines of code (many of them include DateObject) and I will run the EXACT same line and get the following:

[image]

I've tried several different arguments like:

```
DateObject[{2016,2,4}]
DateObject["February 4, 2016"]
DateObject[1]
```

All of them do nothing, and just gives the output the exact same as the input just like above, but with their respective arguments.  the only way for `DateObject` to start working again is for me to quit the kernel and start over again.  Has this happened to anybody else? Is it a known bug? Other thoughts?

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  Do you have the suggestions bar turned on?  [If yes, can you disable it permanently and see if that fixes it?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12406)  What sort of code are you running: do you use undocumented function, modify any builtins or do any other hacks?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10.0.0.0.  And no, I am not using anything weird like that.  I will try turning off the suggestions bar

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: 10.0.0 is known to have several bugs.  You really should upgrade to at least 10.0.2.  If your license allows, upgrade to 10.3.1 instead.

Comment: It's hard to reproduce, as you say. It would help loads if you could provide a minimal working example. Also please report back if removing the suggestion bar or upgrading helps, as suggested by  Szabolcs

Comment: For me, updating Java has fixed front end tokens